# need help in the update query

Tags: mysql, update, query

```
table name:- **t_ci**
s39   column_name
        176
```

i want to have my table like this

```
s39    column_name
176     176
```

But this query works

```
UPDATE t_ci SET s39=s345  WHERE blueprint_id=1234;
```

But I dont know the column_name `for example s345`. This column_name will be the output of a different query

```
SELECT column_name FROM `t_core_properties` WHERE property_name='Virtual IP Address'
```

I tried this query.

```
UPDATE t_ci SET s39=(SELECT column_name FROM `t_core_properties` WHERE property_name='Virtual IP Address')
WHERE blueprint_id=1234;
```

this comes as

```
s39    column_name
s360     176
```

But it adds only the column_name not the value inside that.

I tried using the Mysql User defined Variables

```
SET @column = (SELECT column_name FROM `t_core_properties` WHERE property_name='Virtual IP Address');
UPDATE t_ci SET s39=@column WHERE blueprint_id IN(SELECT id FROM `t_core_blueprints` WHERE NAME='VMWare VCenter');
```

I get the same result as before.

Answer (score 2):

The task can be solved using dynamic SQL. Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE assing_value(propertyname TEXT, blueprintid BIGINT)
BEGIN
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE t_ci SET s39=', column_name, ' WHERE blueprint_id=', blueprintid)
  INTO @sql
  FROM t_core_properties
  WHERE property_name=propertyname;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
END;
```

and then

```
CALL assing_value('Virtual IP Address', 1234);
```

---

or the same in plain code:

```
SET @column := ( SELECT column_name 
                 FROM `t_core_properties` 
                 WHERE property_name='Virtual IP Address');
SET @sql := CONCAT('UPDATE t_ci SET s39=', 
                    @column, 
                   ' WHERE blueprint_id IN (',
                   ' SELECT id',
                   ' FROM `t_core_blueprints`', 
                   ' WHERE NAME=\'VMWare VCenter\')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

Comment: I used the second code. it worked. Genius